# Mustache for PHP partial templates

Tags: php, templates

I am trying to do some Moustache templating using Moustache for PHP  and running into an issue I don't know how to do.

I have an array with a member called Designations that can have multiples of about 6 values.
I need to return an html table with an image for each of the designations.

Let's say that the array has these values:

```
$data = array("Designations"=>"CC,RM,SR", "YearsDesignated" => "1989, 2003, 2006");
```

How would I generate, using Moustache this resulting table:

```
<table class="table table-condensed" style="width: 100%;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:center; width: 16%;"><img src="images/cc-46x40.png" alt=""><br />CC Since: 1989</td>
      <td style="text-align:center; width: 16%;"><img src="images/rm-30x40.png" alt=""><br />RM Since: 2003</td>
      <td style="text-align:center; width: 16%;"><img src="images/sr-40x40.png" alt=""><br />SR Since: 2006</td>
      <td style="text-align:center; width: 16%;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="text-align:center; width: 16%;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="text-align:center; width: 16%;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm presuming the usage of a Partial but not sure how to do this.

Comment: generating the markup is easy, but the most difficult is to find a way to pass the image filenames, are you sure you can't store them in a pattern like a stanard 40x40px? .. so it can be the same all

Comment: I guess I could rename them all without the size making them like CC-thumb.png

Comment: that would make it easier, try exploding with `explode` the values o `$data` by `,` (comma) delimiter to get array values and the loop for generating markup

Comment: Put the last comment as answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I ended up doing this:

**Mustache template:**

```
<table class="table table-condensed" style="width: 100%;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    {{# Designations}} 
      <td style="text-align:center; width: 16%;"><img src="images/{{Desig}}-46x40.png" alt=""><br />{{Desig}} Since: {{Year}}</td>
    {{/ Designations}} 
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**data:**

```
$data = array("Designations"=>array(
            array("Desig"=>"CIC", "Year"=>1989), 
            array("Desig"=>"CRM", "Year"=>2003), 
            array("Desig"=>"CSRM", "Year"=>2006)
    )
);
```

**final render:**

```
<table class="table table-condensed" style="width: 100%;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:center; width: 16%;"><img src="images/CIC-46x40.png" alt=""><br />CIC Since: 1989</td>
      <td style="text-align:center; width: 16%;"><img src="images/CRM-46x40.png" alt=""><br />CRM Since: 2003</td>
      <td style="text-align:center; width: 16%;"><img src="images/CSRM-46x40.png" alt=""><br />CSRM Since: 2006</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

try `exploding` the array values

```
$data = array("Designations"=>"CC,RM,SR", "YearsDesignated" => "1989, 2003, 2006");
$array1 = explode(",",$data["Designations"]);
$array2 = explode(",",$data["YearsDesignated"]);
```

and for the markup, *although not using that specific library*..

```
echo '<table class="table table-condensed" style="width: 100%;"><tbody><tr>';
foreach($array1 as $offset=>$value){
 echo '<td style="text-align:center; width: 16%;">
       <img src="images/'.strtolower($value).'-thumb.png" alt="">
       <br />'.$value.'Since: '.$array2[$offset].'</td>';
}
echo "</tr></tbody></table>";
```

Comment: -1 Yes you say "although not using that specific library.." but by doing so you have not answered the OP's *actual* question and instead have probably made him continue to not use templateing at the detrement of his code